# How to pass user defined function having structure inside main function in C?

Tags: c, function, variables, scope, variable-declaration

How to pass user defined function "add()" having structure inside it to the main() function in C?

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct student
{
    char *name;
    int age;
    float per;
};
void add(){
    struct student o,o2;
}
int main()
{
    // struct student o,o2;
    add();
    o.name="Jay";
    o.age=30;
    o.per=85.5;
    o2.name="Shine";
    o2.age=22;
    o2.per=99;
    printf("\nName        : %s",o.name);
    printf("\nAge         : %d",o.age);
    printf("\nPercent     : %f",o.per);
    printf("\n--------------------------------\n");
    printf("\nName        : %s",o2.name);
    printf("\nAge         : %d",o2.age);
    printf("\nPercent     : %f",o2.per);
 
    return 0;
}
```

If above program is executed it throws error. But we have declared that structure inside add(). so if we call add in main function it should run the struct right ? Why does it throw error?

Whats the difference between type-1 & type-2 ?
Type-1

```
void add(){
    struct student o,o2;
}
```

type-2

```
void add(struct student o,o2);
```

Comment: The `add` function isn't doing anything.  What are your trying to do with it?

Comment: "If above program is executed..." actually you do not execute your program because you cannot even compile it. Errors during compilation are very different from errors when executing.

Comment: The variables are declared in a stack. When returning from a function, all the variables are popped. So this doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void add();
struct student
{
    char *name;
    int age;
    float per;
};
struct student o,o2;
void add(){
    struct student o,o2;
}
int main()
{

    // struct student o,o2;
    add();
    o.name="Jay";
    o.age=30;
    o.per=85.5;
    o2.name="Shine";
    o2.age=22;
    o2.per=99;
    printf("\nName        : %s",o.name);
    printf("\nAge         : %d",o.age);
    printf("\nPercent     : %f",o.per);
    printf("\n--------------------------------\n");
    printf("\nName        : %s",o2.name);
    printf("\nAge         : %d",o2.age);
    printf("\nPercent     : %f",o2.per);
 
    return 0;
}
```

`output:-`

```
Name        : Jay
Age         : 30
Percent     : 85.500000
--------------------------------

Name        : Shine
Age         : 22
Percent     : 99.000000
```

1.you not declared the `void add()` function.

2. your forget to declare the `struct student o,o2` globally.

`type1:-`

```
void add(){
    struct student o,o2;
}
```

this function does nothing until you pass the structure to function. like type2.

`type2:-`

```
   void add(struct student o,o2);
```

In this the whole structure is passed to another function by value. It means the whole structure is passed to another function with all members and their values. So, this structure can be accessed from called function. This concept is very useful while writing very big programs in C.